# Jekyll: Use Different CSS Locally vs Github

Tags: css, jekyll

For my Jekyll-created web site, hosted on github, I'd like to use different CSS locally vs published.

Specifically, when I access it via http://localhost:4000/blah-blah, I'd like some extra page elements to be visible, and when I access it via http://mysite.github.io I want those extra elements to be invisible.

I want to add things like an "Edit Me" button to load the page with http://localhost:4000/admin.

I don't think I can do this with liquid, because the variables are processed at build-time, and I need different values at view-time.

How can I make my Jekyll-built site load different CSS based on the base URL (or hide/show page elements based on the base URL)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with JavaScript.  You could use `document.domain` to get the domain you are in.

```
var localsite = "localhost:4000/blah-blah";
var livesite = "mysite.github.io";

var domain = document.domain;

if(domain == localsite){
  // display edit button
}
```

Something like that might work.  I'm no expert at Jekyll (yet).  There might be some code in jekyll that will help you do this differently and better. You may want to spend some time in the Jekyll docs first.